# Record screen at bootup using ffmpeg in 5 minute segments (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, startup, gnome-classic, ffmpeg, dash-shell

So I've played around with this quite a bit but at this point I've managed to hit a wall in figuring the next step.

I have this script that works from an ssh tunnel to record display :0.0

```
#!/bin/dash
# Sleep to try not to break everything YAY
sleep 30
# Export the main display
export DISPLAY=0.0
#Start an infinite loop
while true; do
        # Set variable now to todays date and the time right now in Hours-Minutes-Seconds_Month-Day-Year
        now=$(date +'%H-%M-%S_%m-%d-%Y')
        # Start recording using ffmpeg at 5fps with a time limit of 300 seconds(Five Minutes) to file $now
        ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -r 5 -t 300 -i :0.0 /home/swuser/Videos/$now.mp4
done
```

I've tried it with an upstart job, but it'll hang startup unless I give it a sleep condition, in which it then doesn't record (I'm assuming it fails to find display :0.0 even if the sleep is before the export) and the script continues to run doing nothing but ending `ffmpeg` over and over.

For reference I'm running `ffmpeg 0.10.12-7:0.10.12-1~precise1`

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Any specific reason to use dash instead of bash?

Comment: No- it's just a note to myself that ubuntu uses dash as the default interpreter for sh scripts.

Comment: another way would be to create a script #2. This script #2 would look like this. 
`#! /bin/bash; sleep 30; ./path_to_original_script`. BTW `ffmpeg` is depreciated and you should use `avconv`

Comment: That could work, I'll try that. Also I don't use the `ffmpeg` package from the Ubuntu repositories, I use the real `ffmpeg` project built from a git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `.profile` file and changing my code around to these:

In `.profile`:

```
if [ "$RECORDISRUNNING" != "1" ]; then
    export RECORDISRUNNING=1
    /home/swuser/sleep.sh &
fi
```

In `sleep.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# sleep for 30 seconds then call record.sh
sleep 30
/home/swuser/scripts/record.sh &
```

In `record.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check to see if there is a display, and if not, exit with error code of 1
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then
exit 1
fi
# Export the main display
export DISPLAY=0.0
# Set variable now to todays date and the time right now in Hours-Minutes-Seconds_Month-Day-Year
now=$(date +'%H-%M-%S_%m-%d-%Y')
# Start recording using ffmpeg at 5fps with a time limit of 300 seconds(Five Minutes) to file $now
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -r 5 -t 300 -i :0.0 /home/swuser/Videos/$now.mp4
# Call the script again (to continually record in 300 second increments)
/home/swuser/scripts/record.sh &
```

And that about wraps it up.